# Select first bacterial isolate of every patient in R

Tags: r

#### Short version:

Using R, I want to identify every first isolate of a patient and give them a value without using a loop, like I am used to with MySQL. I've already accomplished this, but with really ugly `for (i...)` loops and many `if`s and `else`s (syntax below).
Could anyone point me in right the direction for the correct use in R, like `apply` and `by` functions?

#### Long version:

I'm a Ph.D student working on antimicrobial resistance by analyzing the isolates of bacteria we've found in patients. For qualitative epidemiological research on their resistance, you should only include 1 isolate of every genus/species combination per patient per year (since the last isolate date of that patient), and exclude all screening tests. We call that a 'first isolate'. You might else get an overestimate or underestimate of the bacterial resistance for an antibiotic.

Now, I want to migrate to R from MySQL. Doing so, I realize that I shouldn't use procedural code to accomplish the identification of all first isolates. I did, and it worked, but I can't find a way to implement a, let's say, vector/dataframe-way of thinking by using R functions like `apply` and `by`. I would really, really like some help.

The data looks like this; the last column `first_isolate` is what I am after. In the column next to it, I explained why some values should be `1` (click to enlarge).

[image: Data view of isolates]

I've accomplished a valid way of identifying all first isolates with this syntax in R:

```ruby
#define episode (a year)
episode_length_days = 365
# define test codes that should never be a first isolate
exclude_testcodes = c('KWK123', 'KWK456')

# add first_isolate column and fill with value 0
isolate_list$first_isolate <- 0

# loop EVERYTHING and search for first isolates
for(i in 1:nrow(isolate_list)) {
    rowint <- isolate_list[i,]
    
    # save cell values to variables for this row
    ThisRow_PatientID <- rowint[[1]]
    ThisRow_Genus <- rowint[[2]]
    ThisRow_Species <- rowint[[3]]
    ThisRow_TestCode <- rowint[[5]]
    ThisRow_Date <- rowint[[7]]
    
    if(is.element(ThisRow_TestCode, exclude_testcodes)) {
        # excluded test code => not a first isolate
    } else {
        if(ThisRow_PatientID != LastRow_PatientID) {
            # new patient => first isolate
            isolate_list[i,]$first_isolate = 1
            LastRow_Date <- rowint[[7]]
        } else {
            # same patient, check for bacteria
            if(paste(ThisRow_Genus, ThisRow_Species) != paste(LastRow_Genus, LastRow_Species)) {
                # not same bacteria => first isolate
                isolate_list[i,]$first_isolate = 1
                LastRow_Date <- rowint[[7]]
            } else {
                # same bacteria, now check for date
                date_strings = c(LastRow_Date, ThisRow_Date)
                datetimes = strptime(date_strings, format = source_date_format)
                diff_in_days = difftime(datetimes[2], datetimes[1], units = 'days')
                if(diff_in_days > episode_length_days) {
                    # longer interval between collection/report dates than episode => first isolate
                    isolate_list[i,]$first_isolate = 1
                    LastRow_Date <- rowint[[7]]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    # save cell values to variables of this row for comparing next row
    LastRow_PatientID <- rowint[[1]]
    LastRow_Genus <- rowint[[2]]
    LastRow_Species <- rowint[[3]]
    LastRow_TestCode <- rowint[[5]]
}
```

But how do I do this without loops and better R practice?

---

Edit: addition of a single patient: third E. coli should by included.

```
patidnb,genus,species,hoofdgroep,testcode,stamnr,datum,ordernr,first_isolate
1000242,Aerococcus,viridans,Urine,KAL2,2,2009-05-26,BE09220204,1
1000242,Escherichia,coli,Urine,KAL2,1,2008-07-18,BE08290431,1
1000242,Escherichia,coli,Urine,KAL2,1,2009-01-08,BE09020509,0
1000242,Escherichia,coli,Urine,KAL2,1,2009-08-07,BE09320413,1
1000242,Escherichia,coli,Urine,KAL2,1,2009-12-11,BE09500460,0
```

Comment: This post may be what your are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789219/getting-index-of-first-occurrence-of-a-value-in-every-column-of-a-matrix

Comment: please include your data in the question as the output of `dput(head(isolate_list))` it is much easier to answer with actual data rather than a picture

Comment: Some of it can be done using `dplyr` package. You just group the data by patient id, and bacteria, then in summarize function you write a formula identifying the first ever record within each group... then you need to take care of the "more than year ago case"...

Comment: as @ira said, but use the function `row_number()` to filter out the first row. Something like `df %>% group_by(g) %>% filter(row_number(date)==1)`

Comment: @Thanos I read this, but I can't get it to work with my columns and (foremost) the date part...

Comment: @Wietze314 or `top_n()` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update 2021**

The `AMR` package for R now has a `get_episode()` and `is_new_episode()` function. The first gives a vector of the index of an episode, the second one a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE`:

```r
library(AMR)
library(dplyr)

# this uses `df` from an answer above
df %>%
  group_by(patidnb, genus, species) %>%
  # the two types of episode determination:
  mutate(episode_index = get_episode(datum, episode_days = 365),
         episode_logical = is_new_episode(datum, episode_days = 365)) %>%
  # selecting relevant columns:
  select(group_vars(.), datum, episode_index, episode_logical)

#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   patidnb, genus, species [3]
#>   patidnb genus       species   datum      episode_index episode_logical
#>     <int> <chr>       <chr>     <date>             <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 1000019 Proteus     mirabilis 2011-03-02             1 TRUE
#> 2 1000020 Escherichia coli      2016-06-21             1 TRUE
#> 3 1000024 Candida     glabrata  2008-11-17             1 TRUE
#> 4 1000024 Candida     glabrata  2009-11-12             1 FALSE
#> 5 1000024 Candida     glabrata  2009-11-22             2 TRUE
#> 6 1000024 Candida     glabrata  2012-11-26             3 TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

Data I use:

```
df <- structure(list(patidnb = c(1000019L, 1000020L, 1000024L, 1000024L, 1000024L, 1000024L), 
                   genus = c("Proteus", "Escherichia", "Candida", "Candida", "Candida", "Candida"), 
                   species = c("mirabilis", "coli", "glabrata", "glabrata", "glabrata", "glabrata"), 
                   hoofdgroep = c("Urine", "Urine", "Pus", "Pus", "Respiratoir", "Respiratoir"), 
                   testcode = c("KAL2",  "KWK", "KGI", "RESDEP", "KGI", "RESDEP"), 
                   stamnr = c(1L, 1L,  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                   datum = structure(c(15035, 16973, 14200, 14560, 14570, 15670), class = "Date"), 
                   ordernr = c("B011090622", "0016252092", "BW09050083", "BW09050083", "BW09050092", "BW09050092"), 
                   eerste_isolaat = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
                   first_isolate = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)),
              .Names = c("patidnb", "genus", "species", "hoofdgroep", "testcode", "stamnr", "datum",  "ordernr", "eerste_isolaat", "first_isolate"), 
              row.names = c(NA, -6L), 
              class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here is a simple example. You might want to change the way the `group_by` is constructed.

```
library(dplyr)
exclude_testcodes = c('KWK123', 'KWK456')

df %>% mutate(datum = as.Date(datum, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  filter(!(testcode %in% exclude_testcodes)) %>%
  group_by(patidnb, genus, species) %>%
  mutate(interval = difftime(datum,lag(datum))) %>%
  filter(row_number(datum)==1 | interval > '365 days')
```

FINAL EDIT:

Because of the iterative nature of defining when the measurement is 'new' according to the 365 days criteria, I had to implement some sort of loop. Maybe you can ask in a different question, how this would also be possible within a dplyr chain.
I only use the loop to define new era's (`ep`) of 365 days:

```
df2 <- df %>% group_by(patidnb, genus, species) %>% 
  mutate(interval = coalesce(as.numeric(datum - lag(datum)),0))

lst <- split(df2, list(df$patidnb, df$genus, df$species))
df3 <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
  cumint = 0
  ep = 1
   for(i in seq_len(nrow(x))){
     cumint <- cumint + x[i,'interval']
     if(cumint > 365){
       ep = ep + 1
       cumint = 0
     }
     x[i,'ep'] <- ep
   }
  x
})

df4 <- do.call(rbind, df3)

df4 %>% group_by(patidnb, genus, species, ep) %>% mutate(first_isolate_n = +(row_number(datum)==1)) %>%
  select(-hoofdgroep, -testcode, -stamnr, -ordernr, -eerste_isolaat)
```

which gives:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 8]
Groups: patidnb, genus, species, ep [5]

  patidnb       genus   species      datum first_isolate interval    ep first_isolate_n
    <int>       <chr>     <chr>     <date>         <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>           <int>
1 1000020 Escherichia      coli 2016-06-21             1        0     1               1
2 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2008-11-17             1        0     1               1
3 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2009-11-12             0      360     1               0
4 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2009-11-22             0       10     2               1
5 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2012-11-26             0     1100     3               1
6 1000019     Proteus mirabilis 2011-03-02             1        0     1               1
```

Comment: This doesnt address the difference greater than 365, only the first row per group condition.

Comment: Thanks for your help! This gives me an error `no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"`. Am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, I assumed the name of your dataframe is df. So change `df` to the name of your dataframe.

Comment: Great, I almost got it! Your syntax almost does what I need. The date difference is not calculated from the last isolate found in a patient. If you look at the image I posted in my question, you can see patient 1000242. His third _E. coli_ should be included, since it has been more than a year since his first _E. coli_ (but the second isn't, so that indeed shouldn't be a first isolate). Now, your syntax calculates the difference between his second and third _E. coli_. Please pull me through, almost there!

Comment: I made a small mistake in the interval calculation. I have switched the parameters now. I could also have used `abs()`.

Comment: No, I think that part worked fine. I've added some CSV lines to my question above for one patient. His third _E. coli_ should be in our filter, now it's not. That row has a date that is **less** than a year ahead compared to the second _E. coli_, but **more** than a year since the first _E. coli_. And must be included because of that. Can you do that? Would be great :)

Comment: oef. that is a bit more complex than comparing with the previous row alone. I understand what you mean though, and I normally use `joins` for that kind of 1:n comparisons.  I think in the end there will need to be some sort of loop mechanism, since the column `first_isolate` will depend on the previous rows of `first_isolate`. I have to think about this.

Comment: changed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dplyr, to do this with a little bit of work:

```
library(dplyr)
first_isolate %>% #your data
 group_by(patidnb, genus, species) %>%#grouped by these rows
 mutate(first = +(row_number() == 1| (datum - lag(datum))>365))
```

The last call is a little tricky - we make a boolean of either the first row in a group, or the difference from the current date to the previous date in a group is >365. Then we convert these TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 using the `+()`

data (with added rows to show the >365 clause):

```
first_isolate <- structure(list(patidnb = c(1000019L, 1000020L, 1000024L, 1000024L, 
1000024L, 1000024L, 1000024L, 1000024L), genus = c("Proteus", 
"Escherichia", "Candida", "Candida", "Candida", "Candida", "Candida", 
"Candida"), species = c("mirabilis", "coli", "glabrata", "glabrata", 
"glabrata", "glabrata", "glabrata", "glabrata"), hoofdgroep = c("Urine", 
"Urine", "Pus", "Pus", "Respiratoir", "Respiratoir", "Respiratoir", 
"Respiratoir"), testcode = c("KAL2", "KWK", "KGI", "RESDEP", 
"KGI", "RESDEP", "RESDEP", "RESDEP"), stamnr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), datum = structure(c(15035, 16973, 14270, 
14270, 14270, 14270, 14730, 15180), class = "Date"), ordernr = c("B011090622", 
"0016252092", "BW09050083", "BW09050083", "BW09050092", "BW09050092", 
"BW09050092", "BW09050092"), eerste_isolaat = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), first_isolate = c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)), .Names = c("patidnb", 
"genus", "species", "hoofdgroep", "testcode", "stamnr", "datum", 
"ordernr", "eerste_isolaat", "first_isolate"), row.names = c(NA, 
8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

output (using a select to make sure we show the new column):

```
first_isolate %>% 
   group_by(patidnb, genus, species) %>% 
   mutate(new = +(row_number() == 1| (datum - lag(datum))>365)) %>% 
   select(datum,new)

Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
Groups: patidnb, genus, species [3]

  patidnb       genus   species      datum   new
    (int)       (chr)     (chr)     (date) (int)
1 1000019     Proteus mirabilis 2011-03-02     1
2 1000020 Escherichia      coli 2016-06-21     1
3 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2009-01-26     1
4 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2009-01-26     0
5 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2009-01-26     0
6 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2009-01-26     0
7 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2010-05-01     1
8 1000024     Candida  glabrata 2011-07-25     1
```

Comment: your solution does not address the exclusion of test codes.

Comment: I think you've missed a bracket `)` at the end. But when I run it, I get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'first_isolate' not found`, so I retried it with `with(isolate_list, [your code])`, but then I get `no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"`. Any ideas?

Comment: it looks like you have some other packages loaded (maybe plyr?), which are interferring with dplyr. try replacing the `group_by` with `dplyr::groupby` and probably also the `mutate` with `dplyr::mutate`, and possible the `lag` with `dplyr::lag`. also make sure you are using a dataframe at the first position (ie, `first_isolate`)

Comment: (comment removed)

Answer (score 0):

Although @Wietze314 has pointed me in the right direction (and got my credit as answer), I'll post my own solution here to help others possibly.

I ended up with this `dplyr`:

```ruby
df <- isolate_list  %>%
  # filter out test codes that should be excluded
  filter(!(testcode %in% exclude_testcodes)) %>%
  # recreate date column
  mutate(datum = as.Date(datum, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  # group by patient and bacteria
  group_by(patidnb, genus, species) %>%
  # calculate interval in days
  mutate(interval = as.double(difftime(datum,lag(datum), units = 'days'))) %>%
  # accumulate interval in days for this patient, for this bacteria
  mutate(interval_cum = if_else(is.na(interval) | (paste(genus, species) != paste(lag(genus), lag(species))), -1, interval + lag(interval))) %>%
  mutate(interval_cum2 = if_else(lag(interval) > episode_length_days, 0, interval_cum)) %>%
  # filter out first row and all relevant accumulated intervals
  mutate(first_isolate_dplyr = if_else(row_number(datum) == 1 | interval > episode_length_days | interval_cum == -1 | interval_cum2 > episode_length_days, 1, 0, 0))
```

This got me almost to the truth; a frequency table tells me that 676/1000 is a first isolate according to my `for(i...)`, and 671/1000 according to this `dplyr`, with a difference in a total of 11/1000 isolates.

### tl;dr

**If anyone knows a way to select/identify/filter only one row every 365 days on a column with dates, you're welcome to join :)**

Comment: I edited my answer for the final time. To make sure there is no problemen with a longer sequance of measurements. That is were your `dplyr` chain goes wrong.